# Equivalent of callAsyncJavascript (IOS) for Android Webview

Tags: android, swift, flutter, android-webview, wkwebview

I'm working on a project which uses a webview on IOS and Android. I have some native methods which call some javascript methods with the `evaluateJavascript` webview method which is available from the [IOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript) and [Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)).

Since I need to get the result of a JS promise, I'm using [callAsyncJavascript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/3656441-callasyncjavascript) on the IOS side.

The issue is I can't find any `callAsyncJavascript` on the Android side but I saw that it exists on [Flutter](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/javascript/injection/#Using-the-callAsyncJavaScript-method).

Did someone have some knowledge about this? Is there some equivalent on Android? Or how does Flutter manage this internally?

Here is some code I'm using on IOS:

```
let script = """
    return window.myJsMethod().then(({id}) => id);
"""
        
webView.callAsyncJavaScript(script, in: nil, in: .page, completionHandler: { result in
    switch result {
    case let .failure(error):
        debugPrint("failure \(error)")
    case let .success(result):
        completion?(result as! String)
    }
})
```

Comment: What *specifically* is it about `evaulateJavascript()` that is not doing what you want for your scenario?

Comment: Thanks for your response :) I need to get the result of a promise but evaluateJavascript does not look ok for this. Actually I did not succeed to get any result with it. I dit not succeed to wait for the value and return it with my native method

Comment: With callAsyncJavascript I'm able to get the result with the completionHandler. I edited my message to add some code

Answer (score 0):

If there is some people interested, I found a way to implement `callAsyncJavascript` on Android by following the implementation of the flutter package [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview)

You can find its code [here](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/blob/f06bcdf695847a0187a31ab607b2bfe236fb0057/android/src/main/java/com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/in_app_webview/InAppWebView.java#L1589)